# How do I modify a local file from within a browser tab?

Tags: browser, text-editor

Does In Browser Text Editors support File->Open and File-Save As functionality?

Comment: *In Browser Text Editors*? What do you mean?

Comment: http://codemirror.net/

Comment: Okay, so you want use these online editors edit your local file. But looks like these online editors don't support that.

Comment: I don't want to leave the browser when editing my local files.